# Unable to install PyMuPDF on Mac 10.14.5

Tags: python, pymupdf

After running `pip install pymupdf` in my conda environment, i get an error when trying to `import fitz`

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fitz'**

Inside my terminal i ran `pip list | grep PyMuPDF` to verify installation and it returns `PyMuPDF 1.14.17`, so im lost as to what the issue is.

Any help on getting this working would be really appreciated.

Comment: are you using the same python as the one from pip?

Comment: @dangom i created my conda env using ```conda create -n my_env python=3.7 pip pandas numpy```.  Running ```conda list``` inside my environment shows ```pip 19.1.1``` and ```python 3.7.3```

Answer (score 0):

pls use `pip install --upgrade pymupdf`
I have the same problem and after used this, my problem solve

Comment: this didnt work for me. Within my existing environment, typing ```pip install --upgrade pymupdf``` returns ```Requirement already up-to-date: pymupdf in /anaconda3/envs/ot_raw_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.14.17)```. For testing, I created a new environment and ran ```pip install --upgrade pymupdf```, which returned ```Successfully installed pymupdf-1.14.17``` , however i am still getting the error ```No module named 'fitz'```during import.